# Need to combine find printf with cksum

Tags: filesystems, find

I've found myself in the horrible position of needing to suck file system data into a database for analysis. One of the ways I was using to extract this data was using the following GNU find command line.

```
find . -printf '__:__%M__:__%u__:__%g__:__%s__:__%Cs__:__%p\n'
```

This uses `__:__` as the separators which in theory will never appear in an actual file or directory name.

The problem is that I now need to also incorporate cksum because I need a quick checksum of the files.

What I *want* to do is to do something like:

```
find . -exec cksum {} \; -printf '__:__%M__:__%u__:__%g__:__%s__:__%Cs__:__%p\n'
```

Which keeps it all as a one liner and a single pass over the filesystem. BUT this outputs the cksum on a separate line.

Is there some way of combining the -exec cksum so it appears as a value I can use in the printf?

Is find the best tool to do this? Should I be using another tool instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some notes:

- There's nothing stopping `__:__` or newline from appearing in a file path, `__:__` cannot occur in any of the fields you print before the path.

  Try `mkdir -p $'__:__/\n\n\n'` if you want to check.

  Any byte value other than 0 can occur in a file path. Those bytes don't even have to make up characters, so generally you can't treat file paths as text, let alone single lines of text. Usually we use NUL-delimited records to represent lists of file paths reliably.
- `%u` and `%g` give you *a* user/group name corresponding to the uid/gid of the file. There can be several user names for one user id and the user name for uid 123 may be something today and something else tomorrow. In other words, what you get is not intrinsic to the file but also embeds information from the system's user database.
- The order of the files  reported by `find` is non-deterministic. If the aim is to be able to detect when something in the directory hierarchy has changed, you'll want to sort that list.
- beware `%Cs` only gives you precision to the second. Use `%C@` for full precision.

Here, you could do (with `zsh` or `bash`)

```
find . -printf '%M/%U/%G/%s/%C@/%p\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -z |
  while IFS=/ read -rd '' mode uid gid size ctime file; do
    cksum=$(cksum < "$file") || continue
    # do what to have to do with $mode $uid $gid $size $ctime $cksum $file
  done
```

You may also want to pick a more reliable checksum algorithm than that of `cksum`.

Note that with `bash`, you can't pick any other separator than `/` above. If you pick `:` for instance and there's a file called `./dir/file:` (with a trailing `:`), `bash`'s `read` splits `mode:uid:gid:size:ctime:./dir/file:` into `mode`, `uid`, `gid`, `size`, `ctime`, `./dir/file` and the trailing `:` is lost. That's a POSIX requirement (ignored by zsh). `/` is guaranteed not to occur at the end of file paths output by `find`.

Also note that the `-printf` predicate is specific to the GNU implementation of `find` and is not portable. `-z` and the ability to cope with non-text data is also a GNU `sort` extension.

Comment: Agree, the use of __:__ as a separator is lazy but it works for me in this instance. cksum is quick and dirty, given the number of files I'm dealing with, using something more robust is going to extend the time required to process all the files. Thanks for your answer, it got me to where I needed to be, much appreciated!

Comment: @davx8342, I've added a note about why `/` is used as the separator in my code.